# In P.J. Plauger's "The Standard C Library" (1992), why are for loops used so frequently instead of while loops in the implementations?

Tags: c

I think I'm getting into such a specific question that there may be no answer, but it seems curious to me. This is a retrocomputing question, I promise, see the last paragraph to see how.

In Plauger's 1992 book, "The Standard C Library", Plauger gives reference implementations that work but are not meant to be the world's most efficient implementation. I'm implementing my own libc for kicks so I'm using this book a lot to understand it. I am also not going to try for super efficiency, for the record, and the reason I'm using Plauger's book is because I'm interested in a simpler C library than the ones that exist today.

One thing that stands out to me is that he uses for loops quite a bit where, to me anyway, a while loop seems more natural. Here is an example: his implementation of strcpy:

```
char* (strcpy)(char* s1, const char* s2)
{
    char *s = s1;
    
    for(s = s1; (*s++ = *s2++)!= '\0';)
        ;
        
    return (s1);
}
```

My own implementation, made before I referenced his, was almost identical but used a while loop:

```
char* strcpy(char* s1, char*s2)
{
    char* su1 = s1;
    const char* su2 = s2;
    
    while(*su1++ = *su2++);
    return s1;
}
```

So here's the retrocomputing part: Plauger was writing in 1992. Is there a specific reason that compilers at the time did better with for loops rather than while loops, or is this just a personal preference of Plauger?

Comment: Well, your solution is presented in Harbison and Steele's third edition from 1991, so it was pretty well known. So I'd vote for personal preference. Certainly nothing in the language was an issue.

Comment: It’s even the approach used in the K&R book, so anyone who’d read that at the time would have known it at some point.

Comment: note that your prototype should remain `char* strcpy(char* s1, const char*s2)` or that will break some compilations when a constant pointer is passed as second argument, and you could skip the copy of the second argument completely then

Comment: While-loop is a limited, special case of for-loop, that only exists for brevity/style/readability.

Comment: @BrianH Interesting. I would have thought that the for loop was built on the while loop instead

Comment: Plauger's coding is sloppy. In the example, `s1` is assigned to `s` twice: in the variable initialization, and in the for-loop initialization.

Comment: When running these 2 implementations through the Godbolt compiler explorer, I could see no significant difference in the output asm that would make any performance delta, at least for gcc 4.8.5 on Power architecture and gcc 4.5.4 on ARM. However, 6502 cc65 results in a bit shorter code with the while loop, do not know if it is quicker.

Comment: @GlenYates a fascinating question (well, probably not *fascinating*, but to me it is) is: which versions of the compilers listed in the book (Borland, "Project GNU", and VAX ULTRIX) was he using, and were there any differences for those versions?

Comment: `for(s = s1; (*s++ = *s2++)!= '\0';)` would never pass a code review nowdays.  Spend some more lines of code, make it readable.  It will compile to the same thing.

Comment: @Kingsley It annoys me to see sentiment like this. I am fairly sure it comes from a place where people don't want to learn how C `for` loops work, and only ever want to pattern match all code against `for (int x = (…); x < (…); x++)` so that they can pretend they understand what it does.

Comment: @user3840170 - For me it comes from reading thousands of lines of code every day.  In these sorts of complex operator-precedence situations I have to stop, tease apart what's going on, decide if this is a source of a problem, then continue on to the next line.  IMMHO code needs to be written for the *least* capable person who will read it, not the *most*.  Expecting *every* person reading the code to be a language-lawyer (or stop and look it up) is (again IMMHO) bad programming.  Extra lines of simpler code is much quicker to read & debug than less lines of more complex code.

Comment: I am in the same situation as you -- writing a C library, and using Plauger as an important reference on fine print that would probably have escaped my attention otherwise. I have to second Leo's sentiment: The code presented in the book exhibits all kinds of questionable habits, and could IMHO have been presented in a more legible way. It is definitely not a book on clean coding practices. That being said, it could also have been much worse, and is at least *correct* AFAICT.

Comment: Sidenote, your own `strcpy` implementation has some issues: 1) `s2` should be declared `const char *`, not `char *`. 2) Since C99, both arguments should be declared `restrict`. 3) Declaring `su2` is unnecessary, as `s2` should already be `const`. 4) You, too, are assigning `s` twice. And as a personal matter of taste, I despise `for` / `while` / `if` not followed by `{`, and prefer [making empty loops very much explicit](https://github.com/DevSolar/pdclib/blob/master/functions/string/strcpy.c), for clarity and robustness when code is added later (when a trailing semicolon might be overlooked).

Comment: You can write any type of loop as a `for` loop. Thus, for many C programmers, `for` becomes the idiomatic way of doing it. I certainly find it much easier to standardize on `for` than having to think about all different kinds of loop structures/syntax. There are always multiple ways of writing the same code. Pick the one you find easiest to read and/or easiest to write without bugs.

Comment: This reminds me of something I read decades ago. I don't remember who wrote it, but it's one of the folks who were writing books about programming back in the days of Plauger and Steele. To the best of my memory, this is the quote: "As time goes on, computer time gets cheaper, and man-hours get more expensive." In other words, write easy-to-understand code, even if it uses more statements and instructions, because a short, complex construct meant to save a few CPU cycles will be more and more expensive to understand and debug as time goes on, while the run resources will continue to decrease.

Comment: Way back when (early 80s, Z-80, Aztec C compiler), someone put this in one of our standard `.h` files: `#define EVER ;;`.  As a result, we had a _too-cute_ local (/in-house) standard of saying `for (EVER)` instead of `while (true)`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> One thing that stands out to me is that he uses for loops quite a bit where, to me anyway, a while loop seems more natural.

That part is already discussed in chapter *[3.5 Loops While and For](https://archive.org/details/TheCProgrammingLanguageFirstEdition/page/n63/mode/2up)* on p. 56 of the very first edition of *The C Programming Language*:

> We have already encountered the `while` and `for` loops. In
>
> ```
> while (expression)
>     statement
> ```
>
> the *expression* is evaluated. If it is non-zero, *statement* is executed and *expression* is re-evaluated. This cycle continues until *expression* becomes zero, at which point execution resumes after *statement*.
>
> The `for` statement
>
> ```
> for (expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3)
>     statement
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> expr1;
> while (expr2) {
>     statement
>     expr3;
> }
> ```
>
> Grammatically, the three components of a `for` are expressions. Most commonly, *expr1* and *expr3* are assignments or function calls and *expr2* is a relational expression.

As to your question:

> So here's the retrocomputing part: Plauger was writing in 1992. Is there a specific reason that compilers at the time did better with for loops rather than while loops, or is this just a personal preference of Plauger?

Yes, it's only a matter of style as K&R notes on p. 57 of their book with:

> Whether to use `while` or `for` is largely a matter of taste.
> For example, in
>
> ```
> while ((c = getchar()) == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
>      ; /* skip white space characters */
> ```
>
> there is no initialization or re-initialization, so the `while` seems most natural.
>
> The `for` is clearly superior when there is a simple initialization and re-initialization(*1), since it keeps the loop control statements close together and visible at the top of the loop. This is most obvious in
>
> ```
> for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
> ```
>
> which is the C idiom for processing the first N elements of an array, the analog of the Fortran or PL/l DO loop.

So Plauger might simply be used to a preference of `for` loops shown by the base material and many many examples derived from it.

**Take Away #1:** Code writing is always a matter of style preference.

The book goes on a bit about further savings in source lines, showing a clear preference of K&R for writing tight source code, almost as readable as APL (but... see below). Of course there could be other PoV.

The discussion about the merits of either version is already there in the very first book about C, more than a decade before Plauger's writing.

**Take Away #2:** Reading the basics first is a great idea before switching to secondary literature :))

But there's also the **but**-part about *some* compiler shortfall: Some of these compacting line saving techniques were also hints for the compiler - or better ways to make less 'intelligent' compilers generate the best code. A line like `*s1++ = *s2++` can be turned into an assignment with auto increment operations without much lookahead or reshuffling. Even better, on a CPU which sets the flags according to the last item moved, it spares an additional test for a trailing zero byte (*2).

So even the dumbest compiler, used for a CPU with auto increment and flags set by move will choose the best possible code - and that's what a PDP-11 was. It's one of the artefacts showing that while C may be seen as CPU independent, it was in all practical use constructed to best support a CPU with certain features.

This kind of compiler support became useless if not superficial the moment C was ported to different CPUs (*3) as well with more sophisticated compilers.

**Take Away #3:** There is a part of compiler hacking included in using such constructs. Even though it was already way outdated when Plauger wrote his book.

---

### A different POV about Style, readability and meaning.

In the mind of K&R `for` is kind of a combination of COBOL and APL: the readability of COBOL by putting all items necessary for (basic) loops into a defined structure, so no need to look around for initialization, while keeping it compact like some APL code.

But when looking at it in a more fundamental way I would consider both implementations presented in the question as bad implementations and note it in any code review.

To start with, using `while` with anything but a test expression is using side effects. By definition (check K&R) `while` is a repeating loop, one that is executed ZERO or more times. No execution of whatever it contains will ever happen if the condition is not true at the beginning of each iteration. Using it as shown goes against that basic principle.

After all, the task of copying a (zero) delimited string needs to transfer at least the trailing delimiter. So the task is to transfer 1..n elements, not 0..n.

Similarly, `for` does not fully fit the task, at least not as used. `for` defines an iteration as initialization, condition and reinitialization. Again none of the three should be manipulating anything outside of loop control. Except, when taking the items apart, using a `for` no longer satisfies the need for a 1..n loop - at least not without a lot of temporary variables/constructs.

The grammatically correct construct to describe this is a *do/until* as in *do/while*, so it should look rather like this:

```
  do
     st = *s1++ = *s2++;
  while (st != '\0');
```

Yes, I know, unfamiliar to classic C programmers drilled to save on lines at all cost.

---

*1 - Note the word *re-initialization* got changed to *increment* in the second edition.

*2 - This is BTW why Plauger writes `(*s++ = *s2++)!= '\0'` as that forces an explicit test for a zero value transferred, independent of compiler and CPU type. One step toward real portable code.

*3 - Including x86, which does not set flags according to moves.

Comment: The explicit comparison with zero has nothing to do with portability, beyond the fact that some compilers will issue a warning if an assignment operator is the outermost node of a condition-control expression, and some programmers configure compilers to treat warnings as errors.  Many compilers will squawk at `if (x=y)` but accept `if ((x=y) != 0)` without complaint.

Comment: @supercat, or `if ((x=y))`; IIRC at least gcc accepts and even suggest using that if you really mean it when seeing the `if (x=y)`. Then the next question is if compilers warned about that in the early 90's already? I can't remember.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Turbo C warned about that in the late 1980s.

Comment: `for` loops were common to almost all programming languages at the time. I'm not so sure about `while` -- in some languages you probably had to use explicit `goto` for this.

Comment: It's easier for a simple compiler optimizer to make a guess as to how to parallelize a for loop than a while loop, since at least one of the iteration dependencies is specified at the top of the loop.

Comment: "analog of the Fortran" - did FORTRAN re-calc the limits on loops? I thought it calced only on loop entry?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Well, I would as well say so. You might have to ask the Messrs. Kernighan and. Ritchie what exactly they mean. Personally I would think that the usage of 'analog' indicates that it's about the primary function of a counting loop, not any deeper similarities or tricks that can be played in either language (or not).